# What would be the fastest way to insert 2.5 million rows of data parsed from a text file, into Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

As the question stated I have a text file (700 mb) that I am reading using c#,I am parsing the 2.5 million lines, converting each line into a class, serializing the class, then inserting into a sql-server-2012 database.

The table I am inserting into has two columns and looks like:

```
{Auto_Increment_id: Serialized Byte Array}
```

My current strategy is to parse about 10000 lines, insert them into the database, and then repeat. This is taking about 3 hours to do, so I am sure there is a more efficient way.

One thought I had would be to write the inserts to a text file and do a bulk copy into the database. Any other thoughts?

Ultimately I want to get this process down to at least 10 - 20 minutes. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you doing anything other with the classes besides inserting? Seems like a lot of extra work, if the text file data is already good, and especially so if the text data is compatible (or close) with Sql Server's [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: Yes the classes contain calculations based on the parsed text file. I also plan on using the classes again after I insert to do more aggressive calculations.

Comment: Run a profiler on a representative subset of the operation of the program. That will tell you what parts are slow. Concentrate your efforts on those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy. Read about it. IN the documentation.

FASTER - because it is not really written smart - is to make this into a temp table, then at the end of that insert into the final table. SqlBulkCopy locks the whole table, this bypasses it and allows the table to be used during the upload.

Then use multiple threads to insert blocks of a lot more than 10000 rows per go.

I manage more than 100.000 rows - per second - on a lower end database server (that is 48gb memory, about a dozen SAS discs - and yes, that is lower end).